# In which order joins execute in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have written sql query, with three joins.

```
select *from table1  
LEFT JOIN table2 TTS on table1.field1=  table2.field2 
INNER JOIN  table3 on table1.field3 =  table2.field4
```

My requirement is that I want all entries of table1 so made left join with table2. After that I want to Inner join with table3. So Please tell be what in which order sql query will execute Left to Right or Right to Left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `join`s are *logically* implemented in the order they are written (unless parentheses change the order).  So, as written, your joins are *logically* implemented as you intend.

The way the query is actually run is left to the execution engine.

Further, your query is equivalent to:

```
select . . .
from table1 INNER JOIN
      table2 TTS
      on table1.field1 = table2.field2 INNER JOIN
      table3
      on table1.field3 = table2.field4  ;
```

Why?  The `LEFT JOIN` might produce rows from `table1` that have no matches in `table2`.  `field4` would be `NULL` in these rows, and the second `on` would filter them out.

Typically, in queries that use `left join`, all `join`s after the first are `left join`.  So you probably intend:

```
select . . .
from table1 LEFT JOIN
      table2 TTS
      on table1.field1 = table2.field2 LEFT JOIN
      table3
      on table1.field3 = table2.field4  ;
```

This will keep all rows in `table1` regardless of matches in the other two tables.